# Handle Authorization and Authentication in DDD

Tags: authentication, authorization, domain-driven-design

currently i am trying to deal with authorization and authentication on .net core API

There is a company, and that company can create custom roles.
Those roles, will have permissions inside it, such as:

- Read
- Write
- Delete

The company, can apply a role to the users that he creates

With that said, how would i handle the authorization part?

Because, i believe this is considered business logic.

How should i approach this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can create the role and add claims to that specific role and policy for authorization

```
AddAuthorization((options) =>{
  options.AddPolicy("UserCreation", policy =>
  policy.RequireRole("Admin").RequireClaim("Admin", "Edit"));
```

by using the role manager in.net core identity you can add the claim to the role

```
RoleManager<Role> _roleManager;
_roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, claim);
```

last you can check whether the user have the role and claim to access the resource using authorize attribute

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin", AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Policy = "UserCreation")]
```

Comment: that looks like a good path, but the thing is, those roles can be anything, because the super user, is allowed to create any type of roles
should i just use the claims instead?

Comment: @filipe you can use the claims to implement authorization. This is good article to refer https://procodeguide.com/programming/aspnet-core-identity-claims

Comment: will try to, that looks a good approach

Comment: the thing is, that in that example, they are using a web mvc, here i will have the backend as an API and the frontend as a sepparate project

Answer (score 0):

You can probably handle this in multiple different ways. I'd suggest, since you are referring to an API, to decorate the `Controllers`, `Routes` or both with the `[Authorize]` attribute, where you want the rules to apply.

And you would use this attribute as such (where `foo, bar, baz` - are the roles on the authenticated user).

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "foo,bar,baz")]
```

You can also define the challange scheme like

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "foo,bar,baz", AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: the thing is, how would this apply, if my roles had the hability to be attributed with permissions, like i mentioned above?

Comment: @filipe not sure I follow. The defined role(s) on the Authorize-attribute defines which role(s) the authenticated user must have to active the function. I don't believe you can sub-divide the rules further. The role is a string literal as far as I know, not a complex data-type.
So you can literally have the three roles mentioned "Read, Write, Delete". If you then Authorize-attribute a function with "Read, Write" - only the Read and Write role is allowed to use that function. But I would not recommend those names on roles, rather something like "Admin, HR, User, ...".

Comment: hmm i see what you mean and it makes sense...
but, what i mean is, assign for example the role "Admin" with permissions like "read, delete.." how would i approach that?

Comment: @filipe so if I understand you correctly, let's say you have three roles `Admin, HR, User` and let's pick the HR role as an example. For a particular API route `api/v1/employee/create` annotated with `Roles = "HR"`, not all HR-roles within the system are allowed to execute that route? So you wanna sub-divide HR more? Why not have an explicit role for that explicit function then?
But sure, if you were to sub-divide it, the role HR let's you step into the function - then you could inspect the HttpContext Claim and look for another role or even the username, very hacky. This is not recommended.